# Random effects for mutually inclusive grouping factors

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, misspecification

I am trying to fit a model on a set of data (e.g. 10,000 observations with 20 explanatory variables). The observations belong to 30 groups, **G1**, **G2**, **G3**, ... **G30**, so I need to account for the grouping factor by random effects. The problem is that many observations belong to several groups. For example, **obs1** belongs to groups **G1** and **G5**, **obs2** belongs to **G12**, **obs3** belongs to **G5** and **G12**, etc. If each observation belonged to only one group I would include the random effects as `(1|grouping_factor)`, in terms of the syntax of *lmer*, where grouping_factor is a categorical variable with 30 levels. But they belong to multiple groups. I know one way is to create new groups by combining the other groups, but that is not ideal, because it won't capture the similarities, for example, between the joint groups **G1G2** and **G1G3**. What is a better way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps this is related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411159/using-indistinguishable-subjects-as-predictors-random-effects